# Node-JS - Express and child_process capturing output

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

I am wondering if there is a way for me to have an express server handle requests to a child_process process.

For example, I want to be able to send a command to for example cmd.exe, and get the response to emit to the client doing the request.

Thanks.

EDIT:

How I've tried it so far is:

Spawn the child_process via

```
var proc = spawn(config.cmd, config.args, { cwd: config.cwd });
```

And then piping the output via:

```
proc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {res.send(data)});
```

However, this doesn't actually return the data due to it returning the command that was sent. I was wondering if there was a promise function like:

```
proc.stdin.write("command").then
```

This is a process that is not ending after the command, it will keep running. So I cannot just wait for all the responses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run the server: `npm app.js`

```
// app.js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const express = require('express');

const PORT = 10080;

const app = express();
app.use(async (req, res) => {
   const cmd = 'echo "Hello from terminal"'; //replace this line with your code.
   const dir = await exec(cmd);
   res.json(`hello from server + ${dir.stdout}`);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listining on port:${PORT}`));
```

`curl http://localhost:10080`

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : "hello from server + \"Hello from terminal\"\r\n"
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [Keep-Alive, timeout=5],
                    [Content-Length, 48], [Content-Type, application/json;
```